# SPARQL BIND breaks VALUES?

Tags: switch-statement, rdf, sparql, sesame, rdflib

I was using VALUES in many SPARQL queries recently, only to realize that in one of them I was not getting what I was expecting.

Here is a simple case:

```
@prefix ns: <http://some/ns> .

<http://some/uri> a ns:Document ;
ns:A5000 "00003381" ;
ns:A5080 "sredniowiecze" .
```

I am using VALUES to "translate" from nsA5080 literals to URIs. The simple query:

```
PREFIX ns: <http://some/ns>
SELECT  ?document ?u ?p ?lp 
WHERE
{
     ?document ns:A5080 ?p .    
      VALUES (?p ?u) {
            ( "sredniowiecze" ns:MiddleAges )
            ( "other" ns:Other )
    }    
}
```

works as expected:

```
Document    U   P LP 
<http://some/uri>   <http://some/nsMiddleAges>  "sredniowiecze"
```

But if I will change it to:

```
SELECT  ?document ?u ?p ?lp 
WHERE
{
      ?document ns:A5080 ?p .    
      BIND ( LCASE(?p) AS ?lp )
      VALUES (?lp ?u) {
            ( "sredniowiecze" ns:MiddleAges )
            ( "other" ns:Other )
    }    

}
```

I am getting:

```
Document    U   P   Lp
<http://some/uri>   <http://some/nsMiddleAges>  "sredniowiecze" "sredniowiecze"
<http://some/uri>   <http://some/nsOther>   "sredniowiecze" "sredniowiecze"
```

Which does not make any sens to me. Where does the extra tuple come from? In the real query I have ca. 30+ tuples in VALUES and they all land in the results. 
What is more interesting queries that look almost like that one - work just fine everywhere else.

Ideas?

Comment: I am still interested in solving this puzzle, but in the meantime I want to report that adding and removing some spaces around BIND and variables in my original query - fixed it. BUT doing the VERY SAME formatting in the query above - DID NOT work. :(

Comment: If this is a bug, it's probably specific to some particular implementation.  What SPARQL engine are you using?  Jena?  Virtuoso? something else?  And why is this tagged [tag:switch-statement]?  It doens't have anything to do with switch, as far as I can tell.

Comment: The second query isn't quite what you're running.  The output you show has a Document variable, but your second query has DocumentA.  I'm not sure whether that makes a difference or not here, but it makes it harder to reproduce this…

Comment: I can't reproduce this.  See http://pastebin.com/JK3AG3DN for my attempt.  (I 'fixed' the second query to be ?document rather than ?documentA, which what I assume it was supposed to be.)

Comment: I have this problem with Sesame and Python's rdflib. Both produce the same results. I tagged it as switch-statement as in fact I am using VALUES as switch/case. As I said above - in my original query I added and removed some spaces and it started to work as expected. Doing the same in this example did not help. I fixed the second query in the questions too. Thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: Can you show the modified version that *does* work for you?  Analyzing the difference may help in determining the cause.  Also, is there any difference if the VALUES block is placed *before* the BIND?  Or outside (you can do `select … where { … } values (…) { … }`)?

Comment: Just as a general idea, I wonder if rdflib "overrides" the bind with the values (or vice versa, if you swap the order).  What happens if you use a different variable name in the values block (e.g., ?vlp) and then add a `filter( ?vlp = ?lp )`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the problem is that you use both VALUES and BIND to define ?lp at the same time. I suspect no one thought about that happening but in any case as the VALUES is set last it should have precedence in its BGP, however as BIND closes a BGP the result is going to be weird. I suspect that a query like this where you don't use BIND and VALUES on the same variable will work better.

```
SELECT  ?document ?u ?p ?lp 
WHERE
{
      ?document ns:A5080 ?p .    
      VALUES (?lp ?u) {
            ( "sredniowiecze" ns:MiddleAges )
            ( "other" ns:Other )
      FILTER (sameTerm(LCASE(?p), ?lp))
    }    
}
```

Comment: I like that solution, but it looks like I misunderstood how VALUES work. I was expecting it find tuples matching one (or more - if defined) variables. In my case it was ?lp. Interestingly enough, it worked like that for ca. 29 out of 30 queries I created - all following this pattern but with different data. Luckily your solution is just a minor change in my code. Thanks.